# How can I change the Gradio interface so that when the user clicks on "clear", the cursor is automatically placed in the text input above it?

Tags: python, gradio

I'm following the basic Gradio interface from the [Gradio documentation](https://www.gradio.app/docs/interface):

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"

demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")

demo.launch()
```

The interface is:

[image]

How can I change the interface so that when the user clicks on "clear", the cursor is automatically placed in the text input above it?